# Define timeout on AsyncTask function

Tags: android-asynctask, connection-timeout

I want my application to throw a timeout error within 15 seconds of it connecting to the webservice regardless whether the webservice has returned any answer or not. 
Please comment in case anyone needs more details about the same!